# Solve the differential equation $\dot x=Ax$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The problem is:

$$\dot x=\pmatrix{ 9&-6\\ 12&-3}x.$$

I solve for the eigenvalues and got: $\lambda=3\pm6i$

If $\lambda=3+6i$ then you get

$$\pmatrix{ 6-6i&-6\\ 12&-6-6i}=\pmatrix{0\\ 0}.\mbox{}$$

But I am having trouble reducing it down. The solution says the eigenvector is

$$\pmatrix{1\\ 1-i }.$$

Can anyone help me see this?

Comment: @Davide: I don't understand why edit $x'$ notation to $\dot x$ notation. It makes *no* sense whatsoever.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I didn't change this notation, but only the command for matrices.

Comment: @Davide: Well, your name is on that edit (the original suggestion was rejected). :-)

Comment: Gamecocks99 You have asked quite a few questions, now. We encourage you to accept some of the answers you've received - answers which have been most helpful. You can accept only one answer per question. But you can also upvote as many answers as you'd like ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Starting from your computations, note that 
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 6-6i&-6\\ 12&-6-6i \end{pmatrix}=6\cdot\begin{pmatrix} \color{red}{\mathbf{1-i}}&\color{green}{\mathbf{-1}}\\ (1+i)(\color{red}{\mathbf{1-i}})&(1+i)(\color{green}{\mathbf{-1}}) \end{pmatrix},
$$ 
hence both lines are proportional to $\ell=\begin{pmatrix} \color{red}{\mathbf{1-i}}&\color{green}{\mathbf{-1}}\end{pmatrix}$. Multiplying any of them by the column vector $v=\begin{pmatrix} \color{green}{\mathbf{1}}\\ \color{red}{\mathbf{1-i}}\end{pmatrix}$, one gets a multiple of $\ell\cdot v=(\color{red}{\mathbf{1-i}})(\color{green}{\mathbf{1}})+(\color{green}{\mathbf{-1}})(\color{red}{\mathbf{1-i}})=0$, hence $v$ is indeed an eigenvector.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Gauss-Jordan elimination? For instance, multiplying the first line by -12/(6-6i) = -(1+i) and adding it to the second line lets you eliminate the first coefficient, and so on.